# Spring MVC Login Programmatically: No qualifying bean of type MyUserDetailsService

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-security

I have a Spring Application with spring security and it all works great. When I try to login the user upon registration I can't get it to work...

I have searched a lot and discovered that my principal is my UserDetails object thus I need a method that returns it by username which is in MyUserDetailsService:

```
public class MyUserDetailsService implements UserDetailsService {

    private UserService userService;

    @Autowired(required=true)
    @Qualifier(value="userService")
    public void setUserService(UserService us){
        this.userService = us;
    }

    @Override
    public UserDetails loadUserByUsername(final String username) throws UsernameNotFoundException {

        // Programmatic transaction management
        /*
        return transactionTemplate.execute(new TransactionCallback<UserDetails>() {

            public UserDetails doInTransaction(TransactionStatus status) {
                com.mkyong.users.model.User user = userDao.findByUserName(username);
                List<GrantedAuthority> authorities = buildUserAuthority(user.getUserRole());

                return buildUserForAuthentication(user, authorities);
            }

        });*/

        Users user = userService.findByUserName(username);
        List<GrantedAuthority> authorities = buildUserAuthority(user.getUserRoleses());

        return buildUserForAuthentication(user, authorities);


    }

    // Converts com.mkyong.users.model.User user to
    // org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.User
    private User buildUserForAuthentication(Users user, List<GrantedAuthority> authorities) {
        return new User(user.getUsername(), user.getPassword(), user.isEnabled(), true, true, true, authorities);
    }

    private List<GrantedAuthority> buildUserAuthority(Set<UserRoles> userRoles) {

        Set<GrantedAuthority> setAuths = new HashSet<GrantedAuthority>();

        // Build user's authorities
        for (UserRoles userRole : userRoles) {
            System.out.println("----------------------->"+userRole+"<---------------------------------------");
            setAuths.add(new SimpleGrantedAuthority(userRole.getRoles().getRole() ));
        }

        List<GrantedAuthority> Result = new ArrayList<GrantedAuthority>(setAuths);

        return Result;
    }
```

On my controller after register i try to log the user by doing this:

```
             MyUserDetailsService myuds = new MyUserDetailsService();
             UserDetails ud = myuds.loadUserByUsername(user.getUsername());

//           Authentication authentication = new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(user.getUsername(), user.getPassword(),
//                      AuthorityUtils.createAuthorityList("ROLE_CONCORRENTE"));
//           SecurityContextHolder.getContext().setAuthentication(authentication);

             Authentication authentication = new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(ud, null);
             SecurityContextHolder.getContext().setAuthentication(authentication);
```

And i even have the beans autowired:

```
   private MyUserDetailsService myUserDetailsService;
        @Autowired(required=true)
        @Qualifier(value="myUserDetailsService")
        public void setMyUserDetailsService(MyUserDetailsService userdetailsservice){
            this.myUserDetailsService = userdetailsservice;
        }
```

My Bean:

```
<bean id="myUserDetailsService" class="com.setelog.spring.service.MyUserDetailsService" >
<property name="userService" ref="userService" />

    </bean>
```

Comment: Can you add the stacktrace

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There can be many issues with this case
1) have you defined the package within which spring would search the beans
2) Have you defined this class as service (e.g. by using @service annotation)
3) Have you provided its implementation?

Comment: Thanks it was because I didn't have @Service annotation... It helped me a lot :)